# Wireframe modifyer taking over, even if vertex group selected

Tags: wireframe, solidify-modifier

I have this object:
[image]

I'd like to split it so that the top and bottom halves have the wireframe modifier applied, while the middle has the solidify modifyer, and is basically wirefame free.

Here's the vertex groups:
Top & bottom (saved and selected):
[image]
(where the wireframe is supposed to be applied)

And the flat vertex group:
[image]

I've applied both modifiers accordingly, on the said vertex groups:
[image]

And solidify:

[image]

The problem is, wireframe modifier takes over.
No matter how big I make the solidify modifier settings, it's always wireframed:

[image]
This is the best setting I can get.

I'd like the solidified parts to be... solid, without a trace of wireframe in it.

I tried swapping the settings so that Wireframe modifier is first, solidify second, and vice versa, nothing changes signifficantly.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure it will solve it completely, but I would start by trying quad based topology (as opposed to hex based). Blender prefers quads, and modifiers are one of the places where you are most likely to encounter errors using anything else.